Is there a way to add gaseous hydrogen and oxygen to RPA(rocket propulsion analysis software)?
I want to add gaseous oxygen and hydrogen propellants to RPA(rocket propulsion analysis software) for an analysis I am trying. I am wondering if there is some already existing plugin to do this or if there is a way I can do it myself. I don't know much about RPA right now and I am using the free trial. If there isn't I can just use NASA CEA instead.
Thank you
